# Show different images based on page orientation in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, landscape-portrait

I am just trying to find out if is there a way to define different image sources based on page orientation in XAML.

Like:

```xml
<Image>
    <Orientation is landscape>
     <Image.Source = "landscape.png" />
    </Orientation>
    <Orientation is not landscape>
     <Image.Source = "notlandscape.png" />
    </Orientation>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a property of your ViewModel in the code behind of your Page and bind to that using a **[DataTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-7.0#data-triggers)**.

You will need to override the `OnSizeAllocated()` method for that:

**Code behind**

```cs
private SomeViewModel _viewModel = new SomeViewModel();

public SomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = _viewModel;
}

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    _viewModel.IsPortrait = height > width;
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private bool _isPortrait;
```

or

```cs
private bool _isPortrait;
public bool IsPortrait
{
    get => _isPortrait;
    set => SetField(ref _isPortrait, value);
}
```

**XAML**

```xml
<Image>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            TargetType="Image"
            Binding="{Binding IsPortrait}"
            Value="True">
            <Setter
                Property="Source"
                Value="image_portrait.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger
            TargetType="Image"
            Binding="{Binding IsPortrait}"
            Value="False">
            <Setter
                Property="Source"
                Value="image_landscape.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Image.Trigger>
</Image>
```

An alternative would be to use [Visual States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: Thnak you, I will check both.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [Orientation state triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-7.0#orientation-state-trigger).

```xml
<Style x:Key="OrientationStateTriggerImageStyle"
       TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                Value="notlandscape.png" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                Value="landscape.png" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I don't know if you can use it outside of a style declaration like it is demonstrated, but this will indeed achieve your goal without having to add new properties.

Comment: I did not know about this. Learned something else today. Just a suggestion: Maybe update the answer to reflect changing images instead of a background color?

Comment: Good point, very minimal effort on my part to just use the code example from the documentation. I guess that would indeed be worth the extra effort.